# Trigonometry: Solve equation for $\alpha$

Tags: trigonometry

I have the following trigonometric equation:

$$2\sin(\alpha - 45)\sin(2\alpha) = \sin(\alpha + 45)\sin(\alpha)$$

Is it possible to find $\alpha$?

Please also include each step in your solution.

EDIT: Sorry if I haven't mentioned- yes, it is a solution I reached to as a part of an assignment I was given (school). All I wish to know if I can pull $\alpha$ from what I found.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a homework question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: We have just learned some basic identities, which I have already tried using them, without any success.

Comment: Hint: you will require the following identities.$$ \sin(\alpha + \beta) = \sin\alpha \cos \beta + \sin \beta \cos \alpha \cdots(1)$$ $$ \sin(2\alpha) = 2\sin\alpha\cos a\cdots(2) $$ $$\sin(\alpha - \beta) = \sin\alpha \cos\beta - \sin\beta\cos\alpha\cdots(3)$$Note that there are a lot of solutions for this equation, so these identities **will just help you to simplify, since the solutions cannot be found without [technology](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2sin%28%CE%B1%E2%88%9245%29sin%282%CE%B1%29%3Dsin%28%CE%B1%2B45%29sin%28%CE%B1%29).**

Comment: $2\sin(\alpha-45^{\circ})2\sin \alpha \cos \alpha=\sin(\alpha+45^{\circ})\sin \alpha $

$\implies \sin \alpha(4\sin(\alpha-45^{\circ})\cos \alpha-\sin(\alpha+45^{\circ}))=0$

If $ \sin \alpha=0, \alpha=n\pi$ where $n\pi$ any integer.

Comment: @ParthKohli: That's what I typed as an answer.

Comment: @Gigili luckily, I typed it a minute before you :)

Comment: @ParthKohli: Heh, yes! A stitch in time saves nine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formulas you need to use:

- $\sin(x-y)=\sin x\cos y-\cos x\sin y$
- $\sin 2x=2\sin x\cos x$
- $\sin(x+y)=\sin x\cos y+\cos x\sin y$

---

$$2\sin(\alpha - 45)\sin(2\alpha) = \sin(\alpha + 45)\sin(\alpha)$$
$$(2(\sin\alpha\cos45-\cos\alpha\sin45))(2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha)=(\sin\alpha\cos 45+\cos\alpha\sin 45)\sin\alpha$$
Here you can cancel out $\sin\alpha$ from both sides of the equation but you'll need to point out we assumed $\sin\alpha \neq 0$.
$$4\sin\alpha\cos\alpha(\sin\alpha-\cos45))=(\sin\alpha\cos 45+\cos\alpha\sin 45)\sin\alpha$$
$$4(\sin\alpha-\cos\alpha)(\cos\alpha)=(\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha)$$

$$\sin2\alpha-\cos2\alpha-1=\frac 12(\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha)$$
$$2\cos 2\alpha-2\sin2\alpha+\cos\alpha+\cos\alpha+2=0$$
And [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4cos%5E2%28x%29-+4+sinx+cosx%2Bsinx%2Bcosx%3D0) is the solutions. It doesn't seem possible to further simplify it.

Comment: Well, I wanted to make the complete solution invisible (>!) but it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will now try to solve it using your advices.

Comment: $$(2(\sin\alpha\cos45-\cos\alpha\sin45))(2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha)=(\sin\alpha\cos 45+\cos\alpha\sin 45)\sin\alpha$$

$$\implies 2(\sin\alpha \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} -\cos\alpha \frac{1}{\sqrt 2})(2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha)=(\sin\alpha \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}+\cos\alpha\frac{1}{\sqrt 2})\sin\alpha$$

$$\implies 4(\sin\alpha  -\cos\alpha )(\sin\alpha\cos\alpha)=(\sin\alpha +\cos\alpha)\sin\alpha$$

Comment: I think you divided both sides by $\sin\alpha$, which quantity could be zero.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, yes, $\sin\alpha=0$ is a solution, which I've commented in the problem itself. I think, we need to prove/disprove the existence of the other solutions.